# Create Postgres User that can do anything but deletion

Tags: database, postgresql, database-migration

I am trying to migrate a Postgres 9.5 database to another server with a third-party tool.

This is why I want to create a user for this purpose who has the rights to do basically anything but deletion.

I read through the docu and googled a lot already. However, I did not find any way to set that up so that the user has all the rights except for deletion.

Is there something I am missing? Do you guys know a quick and easy way?

Comment: Where is the problem? You can `GRANT` all privileges except `DELETE`.

Comment: Will that also give access to all functions, triggers, etc? That would be the following, right?
`GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | TRUNCATE | REFERENCES | TRIGGER }
    [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { [ TABLE ] table_name [, ...]
         | ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]`
Except for delete obviously.
But it seemed to me as if this would only give access to tables and nothing else?

Comment: Everybody has access to functions by default, so unless you `REVOKE`d the privilege from `PUBLIC`, there is nothing to do. The `TRIGGER` privilege on a table gives you the right to create a trigger. You'll also need to give `USAGE` privileges on schemas.

Comment: Nice, I will try that out. Thanks Laurenz!